# How to setup a HasAndBelongsToMany association with the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-4.x

### What I want

i want to setup a table `tasks` table with a manyToMany relation between the tasks. One task should have many `successors` and one can have many `predecessors`. 
My `tasks` table also has a foreign key to itself, which identifies superior tasks in a oneToMany relation.

The tables look like the following:

```
tasks(id, superior_task_id, [other attributes])
tasks_predecessors(task_id, pre_id)
```

Where `tasks.id` is the primary key, `tasks.superior_task_id` is a foreign key contraint to `tasks` and `tasks_predecessors.task_id` with `tasks_predecessors.pre_id` is the primary key of `tasks_predecesssors`, both attributes of `tasks_predecessors` are foreign keys of `tasks`.

### My status quo

I have tried to use the standard way of creating models from tables: bake in the command line. And used this as my starting point. With this, nothing happend. It was like the `tasks_predecessors` table didn't exist. The files `TasksPredecessors.php` and `TasksPredecessorsTable.php` were created and were fitted with the "belongsTo" associations to the `tasks` table. In the `tasks` table, there were one `Predecessors` association to correct table. With the standard templates and controllers, the data were not accessible.
Now I did some changes to try to set it up as a normal manyToMany relation with both "sides" in one table. 

My Code in `TasksTable.php`:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Tasks Model
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ProjectsTable&\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Projects
 * @property \App\Model\Table\CompaniesTable&\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Companies
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ToolsTable&\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $Tools
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task newEmptyEntity()
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task newEntity(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task findOrCreate($search, ?callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task[] patchEntities(iterable $entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task|false save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false saveMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface saveManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false deleteMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Task[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface deleteManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 *
 * @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
 */
class TasksTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('tasks');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('UsersCreator', [
            'foreignKey' => 'creator_id',
            'className' => 'Users'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('TasksSup', [
            'foreignKey' => 'superior_task_id',
            'className' => 'Tasks'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Projects', [
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Companies', [
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('Predecessors', [
            'foreignKey' => 'task_id',
            'className' => 'Tasks',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'pre_id',
            'joinTable' => 'tasks_predecessors'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Successors', [
            'foreignKey' => 'pre_id',
            'className' => 'Tasks',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'task_id',
            'joinTable' => 'tasks_predecessors'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Tools', [
            'foreignKey' => 'task_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'tool_id',
            'joinTable' => 'tasks_tools',
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('UsersAssigned', [
            'foreignKey' => 'task_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinTable' => 'tasks_users',
            'className' => 'Users'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator
            ->nonNegativeInteger('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('name')
            ->maxLength('name', 128)
            ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('name');

        $validator
            ->dateTime('start_at')
            ->allowEmptyDateTime('start_at');

        $validator
            ->dateTime('end_at')
            ->allowEmptyDateTime('end_at');

        $validator
            ->allowEmptyString('restricted');

        $validator
            ->integer('status')
            ->allowEmptyString('status');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules): RulesChecker
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn('creator_id', 'UsersCreator'), ['errorField' => 'creator_id']);
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn('superior_task_id', 'TasksSup'), ['errorField' => 'superior_task_id']);
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn('project_id', 'Projects'), ['errorField' => 'project_id']);
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn('company_id', 'Companies'), ['errorField' => 'company_id']);

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

My code in `TasksPredecessorsTable.php`:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * TasksPredecessors Model
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\TasksTable&\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Tasks
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor newEmptyEntity()
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor newEntity(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor findOrCreate($search, ?callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor[] patchEntities(iterable $entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor|false save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false saveMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface saveManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false deleteMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\TasksPredecessor[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface deleteManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 */
class TasksPredecessorsTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('tasks_predecessors');
        $this->setDisplayField(['task_id', 'pre_id']);
        $this->setPrimaryKey(['task_id', 'pre_id']);

        $this->belongsToMany('TasksSuc', [
            'foreignKey' => 'task_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'className' => 'Tasks'
        ]);

        $this->belongsToMany('TasksPre', [
            'foreignKey' => 'pre_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'className' => 'Tasks'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules): RulesChecker
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn('task_id', 'TasksSuc'), ['errorField' => 'task_id']);
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn('pre_id', 'TasksPre'), ['errorField' => 'pre_id']);

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

The `$accessible` array of `tasks` looks like the following:

```
protected $_accessible = [
        'name' => true,
        'start_at' => true,
        'end_at' => true,
        'creator_id' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'superior_task_id' => true,
        'restricted' => true,
        'project_id' => true,
        'company_id' => true,
        'status' => true,
        'users_creator' => true,
        'tasks_sup' => true,
        'project' => true,
        'company' => true,
        'predecessors' => true,
        'successors' => true,
        'tools' => true,
        'users_assigned' => true,
    ];
```

And in `TasksPredecessors.php` like this:

```
protected $_accessible = [
        'tasks_suc' => true,
        'tasks_pre' => true,
    ];
```

I access the data in the `tasks_controller` like this:

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['UsersCreator', 'TasksSup', 'Projects', 'Companies', 'Successors', 'Tools', 'UsersAssigned', 'Predecessors'],
        ]);

        $this->set(compact('task'));
    }

public function add()
    {
        $task = $this->Tasks->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $task = $this->Tasks->patchEntity($task, $this->request->getData(), [
                'associated' => ['Tools._joinData'], //adding quantity of tools
            ]);
            if ($this->Tasks->save($task)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The task has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $usersCreator = $this->Tasks->UsersCreator->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $tasksSup = $this->Tasks->TasksSup->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $projects = $this->Tasks->Projects->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $companies = $this->Tasks->Companies->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $successors = $this->Tasks->Successors->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $tools = $this->Tasks->Tools->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $usersAssigned = $this->Tasks->UsersAssigned->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $this->set(compact('task', 'usersCreator', 'tasksSup', 'projects', 'companies', 'successors', 'tools', 'usersAssigned'));
    }

public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Successors', 'Tools', 'UsersAssigned'],
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $task = $this->Tasks->patchEntity($task, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Tasks->save($task)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The task has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $usersCreator = $this->Tasks->UsersCreator->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $tasksSup = $this->Tasks->TasksSup->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $projects = $this->Tasks->Projects->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $companies = $this->Tasks->Companies->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $successors = $this->Tasks->Successors->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $tools = $this->Tasks->Tools->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $usersAssigned = $this->Tasks->UsersAssigned->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->all();
        $this->set(compact('task', 'usersCreator', 'tasksSup', 'projects', 'companies', 'successors', 'tools', 'usersAssigned'));
    }
```

These are the functions created by the bake command.

### My Errors

If I add a task via `/tasks/add`, everything seems to work properly, until I look it up in the `tasks_predecessors` table. It still doesn't contain any entry.
If I now try to view one task via `/tasks/view/1`, the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Predecessors.task_id' in 'where clause'` comes up, with the corresponding SQL query:

```
SELECT Predecessors.id AS Predecessors__id, Predecessors.name AS Predecessors__name, Predecessors.start_at AS Predecessors__start_at, Predecessors.end_at AS Predecessors__end_at, Predecessors.creator_id AS Predecessors__creator_id, Predecessors.created AS Predecessors__created, Predecessors.modified AS Predecessors__modified, Predecessors.superior_task_id AS Predecessors__superior_task_id, Predecessors.restricted AS Predecessors__restricted, Predecessors.project_id AS Predecessors__project_id, Predecessors.company_id AS Predecessors__company_id, Predecessors.status AS Predecessors__status FROM tasks Predecessors WHERE Predecessors.task_id in (:c0)
```

If I try to edit the task, an other error occurs:

```
Warning (2): array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements [CORE\src\ORM\Rule\ExistsIn.php, line 143]
Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=C:\xampp\htdocs\Handwerker_Projektmanagement_IP2021\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php line=988 [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 71]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Handwerker_Projektmanagement_IP2021\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:988) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 168]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Handwerker_Projektmanagement_IP2021\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:988) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 197]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Handwerker_Projektmanagement_IP2021\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:988) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 197]
```

with
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1`
and the SQL query: `SELECT 1 AS existing FROM tasks TasksSuc WHERE  LIMIT 1`

### Conclusion

I can't make an sense of these errors. If I try different things in the `controller` or `...Table.php` files, I will be surprised with different kind of errors, which all don't make sense to me. I hope someone can help me quick, because I could't find anything about this type of relation, which in my opinion is not that uncommon.

Comment: I'm not sure what the tasks_predecessors table is adding, other than confusion. I've never had cause to use it, but I wonder if the [Tree behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html) might be right for you here? If not, it seems like it should be a straight-forward `hasMany` / `belongsTo` association, which don't need that extra table.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks for your contribution. The tasks_predecessors table enables a m:n relation between predecessors and successors. E.g. **Task1** and **Task2** are the predecessors of **Task3** and **Task4**. With a `hasMany`/ `belongsTo` relation you could only portrait **Task1** is the predecessor of **Task3** and **Task4**. **Task2** would not fit  in that association.